# Can the Standing Wave Ratio be deduced from a reflection spectrum?

Tags: optics, waves, spectroscopy

The Standing Wave Ratio (SWR) is the ratio between the peak amplitude of the standing wave and the trough amplitude of the standing wave.

I would like to figure out the SWR within a thin film when illuminated with certain wavelengths of light.

I can predict this if I know the refractive indices, but is there a way to directly measure the SWR using a spectrometer?

Comment: You really just need to know the relative intensities of the transmitted and reflected waves, so I supposed you could use a spectrometer.

Comment: Is it possible to just use the reflection coefficient? It seems that if SWR= (1+r)/(1-r) then from the spectrum (R = r^2) the SWR should be (1+ sqrt(R))/(1-sqrt(R))